# Button click code is not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net

In Button OnClientClicked am calling jquery following, for conformation message from user. 
If user press yes then it should do button click event, but it is not doing.

My java script Code:

```
function OnClientClicked_CheckConfirm(button, args) 
{
    var objhidConfirmMessage = document.getElementById(hidConfirmMessage);
    var objhidConfirmOKBtnText = document.getElementById(hidConfirmOKBtnText);
    var objhidConfirmCANCELBtnText = document.getElementById(hidConfirmCANCELBtnText);
    if (objhidConfirmMessage != null) 
    {
        button.set_autoPostBack(false);
        jConfirm(objhidConfirmMessage.value, 'Confirmation Dialog', objhidConfirmOKBtnText.value, objhidConfirmCANCELBtnText.value, function (r) {
            if (r) {
                __doPostBack(button.get_id(), "");
                blnConfirm = true;
            }
        });
    }
```

Am I missing any thing in `__doPostBack()`.

Needs to call button click event in `pageload()`.

Answer (score 0):

I've had success using the name attribute of the button, rather the ID.  Is there a get_name() method?  Otherwise, name attribute on the element reference to the button.